# p/invoke unbalanced stack error

Tags: c#, .net, c++, pinvoke

I have the following C++ function and C# p/invoke decleration:

```
//C#
[DllImport("capture.dll", EntryPoint = "setup")]
public static extern void captureSetup(int rr);

//C++
extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) void setup(int rr)
```

But I am getting an error about a p/invoke unbalanced stack likely caused by the managed signature not matching the unmanaged signature.

Can anyone see what is wrong with this?

Comment: Are you sure that `setup` uses the C calling convention?

Comment: @EricJ. Yes. This even worked fine before I added the `int` parameter.

Comment: Shouldn't the C# declaration be a Short?

Comment: @chris no, int matches int, 32 bits, but short is 16 bits

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a calling convention mismatch. The C++ code uses `cdecl` by default but the C# assumes `stdcall`. You need to make them match, e.g.

```
[DllImport("capture.dll", EntryPoint = "setup", 
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void captureSetup(int rr);
```

Comment: Great, that worked (I will accept in 3 minutes when it lets me). But why did it work fine when setup had no parameters?

Comment: In cdecl the caller cleans up the stack. In stdcall the callee cleans up the stack. When there are no parameters, nobody has to clean up and the debug assistant can't tell that there is a latent mismatch.

Comment: And by the way, there was another answer, no deleted that discussed size of `int`. One Windows, `int` is 32 bits in both C++ and C#. No problems there.